# Attempt to read property "total_product_quantity" on null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I make a Nested loop which i create a view for show my data.
how can i show data of single query in view.
[**This is my View page**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1u2uD.jpg)

```
 @foreach($products1 as $item1)          <!-- first product loop -->
                  <tr>
                    <td>{{++$i}}</td>
                    <td>{{$item1->productname}}</td>
                    @foreach($products2 as $item2)  <!-- second product loop -->

                      @if($item1->id == $item2->id)       <!-- campare with second one -->

                        @for($k=1;$k<=31;$k++)             <!-- loop for days -->
                          <td id="">
                            {{$log =App\Models\Production_log::select('total_product_quantity')->where('product_id',$item2->id)->where('employee_id','3')->where('log_date',$k.'-'.'12'.'-'.'2020')->first() }}
                          </td>  
                        @endfor

                      @endif

                    @endforeach
                  </tr>
                  @endforeach
```

**this is controller code**

```
public function index($id)
{
    
    $products1 = Product::get();
    $products2 = Product::get();
    $data['dispatch'] = Production_log::where('employee_id','=',$id)->get();
    $dispatch = '01'.'-'.'12'.'-'.'2020';
    
    return view('production.index',compact('products1','products2','data'));
}
```

---

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOeDY.jpg)
**my result query**

```
{{$log =App\Models\Production_log::select('total_product_quantity')->where('product_id',$item2->id)->where('employee_id','3')->where('log_date',$k.'-'.'12'.'-'.'2020')->first() }}
```

**This is my raw output **

```
{"total_product_quantity":"6"}
```

**I need this output**

```
{{$log->total_product_quantity}}
```

view output

```
5
```

Comment: If you are calling model from view, then there is actually no use of laravel mvc, use direct php

Comment: though as per your question, use pluck on the collection obtained `=App\Models\Production_log::where( ['product_id' => $item2->id, 'employee_id' => '3', 'log_date' => $k.'-'.'12'.'-'.'2020'] )->first()->pluck('total_product_quantity'); `

Comment: plunk not worked in view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `select('total_product_quantity')` at `$log` assignment

Comment: since this code is a loop, you need to handle the posibility of null in some loop iteration.

Comment: `{{isset($log) ? $log->total_product_quantity : '0' }}`